# Is $ORIGIN/lib a reasonable RUNPATH for libraries?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

### **Background**

I have a third-party library that has this structure:

```cpp
lib
 ├── liba.so
 └── libb.so // libb.so is NEEDED by liba.so
```

Both have their RUNPATH set to `$ORIGIN/lib` and `liba.so` depend on `libb.so`.

In my first-party project I have the following structure:

```
bin
 ├── liba.so
 ├── libb.so
 └── myexecutable
```

where `myexecutable` depend directly on both `liba.so` and `libb.so`. `liba.so` still depends directly on `libb.so`. The RUNPATH of `myexecutable` is `$ORIGIN`.

- `./myexecutable` can resolve `liba.so` since `$ORIGIN/liba.so = <path-of-myexecutable>/liba.so = ./liba.so` exists
- `./liba.so` can't resolve `libb.so` since `$ORIGIN/lib/libb.so = <path-of-liba.so>/lib/libb.so = ./lib/libb.so` does not exist. **This is a problem when using CMake's `RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY_SET` to "automatically" install imported library targets**.

### Here's what I think.

It makes sense that *executables* have a RUNPATH `$ORIGIN/lib` and *libraries* have a RUNPATH `$ORIGIN` if the structure resembles this:

**Case: lib**

```cpp
.
├── lib
│   ├── liba.so
│   └── libb.so
└── myexecutable
```

It also makes sense that *executables* have a RUNPATH `$ORIGIN/../lib` and *libraries* have a RUNPATH `$ORIGIN` if the structure is this:

**Case bin+lib**

```cpp
.
├── bin
│   └── myexecutable
└── lib
    ├── liba.so
    └── libb.so
```

Finally, it makes sense that *executables* have a RUNPATH `$ORIGIN` and *libraries* have a RUNPATH `$ORIGIN` if the structure is this:

**Case: bin** (my use-case)

```
bin
 ├── liba.so
 ├── libb.so
 └── myexecutable
```

In all cases above, libraries always have their RUNPATH as `$ORIGIN` and NOT `$ORIGIN/lib`. For this reason it seems wrong to set `$ORIGIN/lib` as RUNPATH for shared object files, since I fail to construct any case where it is preferable to have library RUNPATHs set to `$ORIGIN/lib`.

### Question

If `.so`-files from the same third-party library are expected to live side-by-side in some directory, in presence of NEEDED inter-dependencies, mustn't the `.so`-files with dependencies on other `.so`-files **always** have `$ORIGIN` in their RUNPATH?

---

I understand that this is a discussion I could just have with the third-party library author in context of the actual library - and I am, but I also believe that my question is something that others would benefit from in context of other libraries than the one in my use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If .so-files from the same third-party library are expected to live side-by-side in some directory, in presence of NEEDED inter-dependencies, mustn't the .so-files with dependencies on other .so-files always have $ORIGIN in their RUNPATH?

Yes.

The 3d party vendor who built them with `RUNPATH` of `$ORIGIN/lib` didn't know what he/she was doing.

Comment: And the workaround if you can't get them to fix it is to add a symlink in the lib directory (`ln -s . lib` in that directory)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, until someone else of a different opinion brings forward a reason as to why RUNPATH should ever be `$ORIGIN/lib`